# Caching A Query Daily

Tags: mysql, cache

How to ensure a query runs only once a day in MySQL? Once it runs, returned result should be cached, and even though returned data were changed in database, my query's results should remain the same during the same day. Is that possible?

Point of my this question:

I want to put some statistics on the dashboard of my admin panel. But calculating the statistics keep long time. So, If these calculations is done only one time, it really saves lots of time of my clients and my server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Use MySQL's [`EVENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/event-scheduler.html) mechanism. As the documentation says, it's the MySQL equivalent of `cron` or the Windows `Task Scheduler`. An overview is available from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-overview.html) and an example [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/). They can also be seen as `TRIGGER`s fired by a time rather than by SQL.

Be sure to enable events via the global system variable [event_scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_event_scheduler) as explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/events-configuration.html).

You can set up an event to run at 00:01 and store the result in a table and then your app can refer to that table throughout the day, safe in the knowledge that the value won't change until 1 minute past midnight the following day (or whenever suits you).

Comment: Thank you Verace, but my point is not trigger a query run. My point is if a query runs, its result should be cached and not run till the next day, even if its result is changed.

Comment: But that's precisely my point - you "cache" it by storing your result in a table - unless you have some sort of global variable on the application side that you might want to use (**not** good practice). Maybe if you explain in a bit more depth? And, if you wish to reply to me, put the @ symbol before my name (with the accent) in your reply and I'll be notified.

Comment: I edited my question properly to explain my purpose @Verace